# How to expose GCP Datalab to anonymous user?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I want to deploy a datalab instance to my GCP project with anonymous read access without ssh tunneling.

The documentation specifies one instance per user for read/write and also requires ssh tunneling using the `gcloud` cli.

What is the recommended way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could do it properly using ngrok. (https://ngrok.com) - Ngrox is paid, but has a free version with some limitations.

```
datalab connect mydatalabinstance    
ngrok http 8081
```

and voilá you will get a link like this: http://3340de72.ngrok.io/tree/datalab

And surely you are always able for creating your own reverse proxy.
https://www.techandme.se/set-up-nginx-reverse-proxy/

Best,

Comment: Any free solution?

Comment: Improved the response, but unfortunately I have no other idea for solving this :)